# Is it possible to change the file while uploading a File using Servlet filters?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, servlet-filters

I need to change the file while uploading. example : Whatever the file selected to upload. but i need to upload another file using servlet filters. is it possible?

```
     String applicationPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(""),
            uploadPath = applicationPath + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIR;
       File fileUploadDirectory = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!fileUploadDirectory.exists()) {
            fileUploadDirectory.mkdirs();
        }


    String fileName = "";
    UploadDetail details = null;
    List<UploadDetail> fileList = new ArrayList<UploadDetail>();

    for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
        fileName = extractFileName(part);
        details = new UploadDetail();
        details.setFileName(fileName);
        details.setFileSize(part.getSize() / 1024);
        try {
            part.write(uploadPath + File.separator + fileName);
            details.setUploadStatus("Success");
        } catch (IOException ioObj) {
            details.setUploadStatus("Failure : "+ ioObj.getMessage());
        }
        fileList.add(details);
    }

    request.setAttribute("uploadedFiles", fileList);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/fileuploadResponse.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

/***** Helper Method #1 - This Method Is Used To Read The File Names *****/
private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String fileName = "", 
            contentDisposition = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisposition.split(";");
    for (String item : items) {
        if (item.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            fileName = item.substring(item.indexOf("=") + 2, item.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

But getServletContext() is not supported in servlet filter class. kindly help me how to change the file.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServletContext--. But really, you shouldn't store files there. Not only the path might not exist, but you'd lose the files when you'll deploy a new version of the app. Store data out of the application directory.